# Iwasawa Decomposition Uniqueness Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

**Iwasawa Decomposition** (special case): Let $G=SL_n(\Bbb{R})$, $K=$ real unitary matrices, $U=$ upper triangular matrices with $1$'s on the diagonal (called *unipotent*), and $A=$ diagonal matrices with positive elements ($0$ everywhere else). Then, the product map $U\times{A}\times{K}\rightarrow{G}$ given by $(u,a,k)\mapsto{uak}$ is a bijection.

I have already proved the surjection of this map myself, however, when viewing Lang's proof (Undergraduate Algebra Section 6 Chapter 4 pg246) for the uniqueness of this mapping I became rather stuck and would like to understand it. Lang states the following:

"For uniqueness of the decomposition, if $g=uak=u'a'k'$, let $u_1=u^{-1}u'$, so using $g^tg$ (what does he mean by 'using'?) you get $a^{2t}u_1^{-1}=u_1a'^2$. These matrices are lower and upper triangular respectively, with diagonals $a^2,a'^2$, so $a=a'$, and finally $u_1=I$, proving uniqueness".

What does Lang mean by 'using' $g^tg$ (I presume he means applying $g^tg$ to both sides, but he is unclear...), and so therefore how does he 'get' $a^{2t}u_1^{-1}=u_1a'^2$.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write $gg^t$, you get 
$$
gg^t=uakk^tau^t=ua^2u^t.
$$
Similarly, 
$$
gg^t=u'a'^2u'^t.
$$
If you equate both expressions, you get 
$$
ua^2u^t=u'a'^2u'^t.
$$
Multiply by $u^{-1}$ on the left and by $(u'^t)^{-1}$ on the right to get
$$
a^2(u'^{-1}u)^t = u^{-1}u' a'^2.
$$
So letting $u_1=u^{-1}u'$,
$$
a^2u_1^{-t}=u_1a'^2
$$
where $u_1$ is upper triangular.

Comment: Ah right simpler than I thought thank you! On another note, is it true that when one takes the QR decomposition of a matrix $g\in{SL_n(\Bbb{R})}$, the upper triangular matrix $R$ will have positive elements on the diagonal (this is important for surjection proof). Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can take it with all ones if you want.

Comment: 1) How does equating both equations yield $a^2u_1^{-1}=u_1a'^2$

Comment: 2) In the expression above in Lang's proof it says $a^{2t}u_1^{-1}$, you seem to have missed the little t transpose no?

Comment: The transpose of a diagonal matrix is itself. It's quite weird if he wrote the t on purpose.

Comment: There were further typos in what you got from Lang's book. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your edited answer

Comment: I don't suppose, seeing how well you understand this, if you could help me now complete the whole picture of proving the Iwasawa decomposition as I still feel I have a few holes in the proof - here is the link to my question where I show photos of the proof from Lang's book https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2872455/iwasawa-matrix-decomposition-proof